# Constructor reference helper in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, parameters, constructor

I've ran into this same situation several times:

I'll create a class with multiple constructors, or constructors that accepts many arguments. When I create an object of the class, I'll forget many of the values needed to satisfy that specific constructor. As a result, I'll have to go back into the class to see which arguments are accepted. For me, this wastes a load of time and can derail my thinking process.

Yes, Eclipse will give me the *type* of variable that it needs for each argument, but that doesn't help me with what the value is actually representing.

**Question:**
I was wondering if there was a way to have the compiler pull up the variable *name* instead of the *type*. It would be much faster and I could keep my train of thought going without having to pause and look back at the class for what the values actually represent.

What Eclipse gives me:

```
MyClass pig = new MyClass(height, null, null, height, height, background); //etc
```

(Yes, I know I need an int here, but I know for a fact that's not the height) What I want:

```
MyClass pig = new MyClass(tagNumber, isAlive, isSmelly, weight, age, color); //These are the names of the variables
```

Comment: Do you use javadoc? If not, why not?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan no, are the default names (height, null) part of the default javadoc? Sorry, I haven't been using java for too long so all of the tools are still pretty new to me.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan well after watching a video on this I think my question is surely answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Type some thing like `new YourConstructor(`, then do a Ctrl + Space to see what it suggests and pass values step by step. The default fill is dangerous I never use it.

When your constructors get long (telescopic...) and you have many, you should use static factory methods instead as they can have meaningful names unlike constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert some `javadoc` 'magic' before the method (constructor) body:

write

> /**

and press `enter`

Then you can add all the explanations you want, using html tags for formatting.